# MATLAB: Structure containing an column vector won't display the vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have defined a structures array as such:

```
oRandVecs = struct('vV',{[],[]},...
               'ind_min',{[],[]},...
               'mean',{[],[]},...
               'vV_descending',{[],[]},...
               'largest_diff',{[],[]});
```

`oRandVecs(1).vV` and `oRandVecs(2).vv` both get column vectors assigned to them.  However, the problem is that the output is as follows:

```
>> oRandVecs(1)

ans = 

           vV: [4x1 double]
      ind_min: 2
         mean: 6.5500
vV_descending: [4x1 double]
 largest_diff: 2.8000
```

Instead of actually showing the vector, it only describes its type.

What am I to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer by rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23810890/2586922) is probably the way to go.

An alternative is to convert from structure to cell and then use [`celldisp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/celldisp.html):

```
celldisp(struct2cell(oRandVecs(1)))
```

Example:

```
>> oRandVecs = struct('vV',{[],[]},...
           'ind_min',{[],[]},...
           'mean',{[],[]},...
           'vV_descending',{[],[]},...
           'largest_diff',{[],[]}); %// define empty struct
>> oRandVecs(1).vV = (1:4).'; %'// fill some fields: column vector, ...
>> oRandVecs(1).mean = 5:7; %// ... row vector, ...
>> oRandVecs(1).vV_descending = randn(2,3); %// ... matrix
>> celldisp(struct2cell(oRandVecs(1)))
ans{1} =
     1
     2
     3
     4
ans{2} =
     []
ans{3} =
     5     6     7
ans{4} =
   0.016805198757746   0.236095190511728   0.735153386198679
   2.162769508502985  -0.158789830267017   0.661856091557715
ans{5} =
     []
```

Comment: This is really cool.  I keep refreshing to see your edits :P  BTW, is the mean assignment intentional? `5:4`?  That will give you the empty matrix anyway!

Comment: @rayryeng Whoops! No, the intention was 5:6. Correcting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is because it's simply too big to display on the screen with that structure :) If you want to actually display it, use `dot` notation to display your data.

In other words, do this:

```
 disp(oRandVecs(1).vV);
```

You can also do that with the other variable:

```
 disp(oRandVecs(1).vV_descending);
```

Comment: Well the function doesn't display the vectors but Matlab does, when its being asked to. Is there a way to return it as a line vector with an upper T symbol in the end?

Comment: Upper T symbol I don't think so.  However you can use the [suggestion by Luis Mendo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23810969/3250829), which is a darn good one and I'm glad he thought of it!